# Show that $P \cong C_p \wr C_p$

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory

Let P be a Sylow-p-subgroup of $S_{p^2}$. I need to show that $P \cong C_p \wr C_p$. I didn't get very far yet. I have already proven that $|P|=|C_p \wr C_p|=p^{p+1}$.

Comment: So you just need to show that $S_{p^2}$ has a subgroup isomorphic to that wreath product? Consider writing the $p^2$ element acted on by $S_{p^2}$ as a $p\times p$ square.

Comment: It depends on your definition of wreath products! If you use the definition of wreath products of permutation groups, then it you find that $C_p \wr C_p \le S_{p^2}$ by definition.

Comment: $C_p \wr C_p$ is defined as $C_p \times \dots \times C_p \rtimes C_p$ where the last $C_p$ 'works' on the direct product by permuting the places.

Answer (score 1):

With $G=C_p \wr C_p$ defined as $(C_p \times \cdots \times C_p) \rtimes C_p$, here are two ways that you can show that it embeds into $S_{p^2}$.

For a direct embedding, map the generators of the direct factors of the base group to $(1,2,\ldots,,p)$, $(p+1,p+2,\ldots,2p)$,etc, and the generator of the final $C_p$ to the permutation $i \mapsto i+p \pmod p$. It's clear that the first $p$ generators generate $C_p^p$, so you just need to check that conjugating by the final factor permutes the direct factors.

For a second method, let $H = C_p^{p-1}$ be the direct product of all of the factors in the base group except for the first. So $|G:H|=p^2$. Now you need to prove that $H$ is core-free in $G$; that is, there is no nontrivial normal subgroup of $G$ contained in $H$. That follows from the fact that any nontrivial element of $H$ is conjugate to an element outside of $H$ that projects nontrivially onto the missing direct factor of the base group. So the permutation representation of $G$ on the cosets of $H$ gives you an embedding of $G$ into $S_{p^2}$.